# What would be a walkaround for JavaScript alerts that are generated in a page's onload() using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, onload, rc, javascript

I am automating a form page using Selenium RC (C#). After I click 'Submit' button, I get an alert '`Records Edited Successfully!`'. The title of this alert box is '`The page at http://www.******.com says:`'.

But Selenium doesn't see this alert. And I can't work around it.

Here is what I've tried:

```
selenium.Click("ctl00_Content_ctl00_btnSubmit");
selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

Result: I get the following error: "`Selenium.SeleniumException : Timed out after 30000ms`"

Then I tried:

```
selenium.Click("ctl00_Content_ctl00_btnSubmit");
selenium.OpenWindow("", "The page at The page at http://www.******.com says:");
selenium.Close();
selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

Result: Three windows are opened (site, alert and extra window). Nothing gets closed. I get the following error: "`Selenium.SeleniumException : Timed out after 30000ms`"

Then I tried:

```
selenium.Click("ctl00_Content_ctl00_btnSubmit");
selenium.SelectWindow("The page at The page at http://www.******.com says:");
selenium.Close();
selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

Result: I get the following error: "`Could not find window with title 'The page at http://www.******.com says:'`"

Any suggestions? Please help to overcome this obstacle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a workaround:

```
    selenium.Click("ctl00_Content_ctl00_btnSubmit");                        
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    selenium.KeyDownNative("32");
    selenium.KeyUpNative("32");
```

Wish you all the best, everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the easiest way to do this is to use script to redefine the alert() function to something that doesn't popup a dialog.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) fDriver).executeScript(
  "window.alert = function(msg) { return true; }"
);
```

Comment: Too extreme solution in my case. I don't want (and don't have authority) to change the code of the website.

Comment: I'm not in any way suggesting that you *change* the website... I'm suggesting that in your Selenium script, you "inject" a tidbit of JavaScript when you are running *automated tests* only, to override the alert() function to just return true. ( you can do the same with confirm, etc.) - Since there is no need/desire for user interaction you aren't causing any problems, and certainly not changing the *actual* code base.

Comment: hmm interesting....How do I 'inject a tidbit'? Do I enter it inside my C# [Test] method? Could you give a step by step instructions? Thanks.