# How to handle alert in selenium RC during page load

Tags: selenium

In my application I have alert on pageload.
The alert comes when i visited a specific page of my application and it is on page load.

I tried by:

```
selenium.click("click on the button, which takes me to a new page");
if(selenium.isAlertPresent())
    selenium.getAlert();
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

But no luck. Can any one please help me how to handle alert in selenium RC on page load?

Screenshot:

[screenshot http://content.screencast.com/users/mahadi_OP/folders/Jing/media/77e6c00e-e146-455c-861a-03d3cab9027d/2012-01-08_1703.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/mahadi_OP/folders/Jing/media/77e6c00e-e146-455c-861a-03d3cab9027d/2012-01-08_1703.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know Selenium does NOT support *javascript* alerts that are generated in a page's onload() event handler.  I had the same problem, and the only workaround for me was not to depend on alert in my tests. But maybe these articles will be any use for you:

[Link 1](http://www.mail-archive.com/selenium-users@lists.public.thoughtworks.org/msg00652.html)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210658/what-would-be-a-walkaround-for-javascript-alerts-that-are-generated-in-a-pages)